# Constructor vs. Static Instance Retriever

Tags: java, android, constructor, static

while learning android development I came across the following code section:

```
/**
 * Static initializer for NetworkFragment that sets the URL of the host it will be downloading
 * from.
 */
public static NetworkFragment getInstance(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String url) {
    NetworkFragment networkFragment = new NetworkFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(URL_KEY, url);
    networkFragment.setArguments(args);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(networkFragment, TAG).commit();
    return networkFragment;
}
```

What would be the benefit compared to using a constructor like so:

```
public NetworkFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String url) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(URL_KEY, url);
    networkFragment.setArguments(args);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(networkFragment, TAG).commit();
}
```

References: [Original Android Code](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

Comment: it can (easier) be used to limit the number of instances

Comment: See "Effective Java" Item 1: Consider static factory methods instead of constructors.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that points me in the right direction already.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment need default constructor, to create its objects, it is required, so to pass the argument to ur fragment create static method......., that's is the simple reason